# Wine crashes when trying to run portable version of Firefox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, ubuntu-10.04, wine

I think there is something wrong with my Wine setup, but I don't know how to fix it or even what it is. Others have gotten this program to work without problems in Wine. This is the console output that I get from Wine before it crashes.

> fixme:system:SetProcessDPIAware stub!
>   fixme:dwmapi:DwmIsCompositionEnabled
>   0x33fcd4
>   fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange
>   (Handle 0xdfe994, overlapped
>   0xdfe978): stub fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile
>   I/O completion on lock not implemented
>   yet err:ole:CoGetClassObject class
>   {591209c7-767b-42b2-9fba-44ee4615f2c7}
>   not registered
>   err:ole:CoGetClassObject class
>   {591209c7-767b-42b2-9fba-44ee4615f2c7}
>   not registered
>   err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class
>   object
>   {591209c7-767b-42b2-9fba-44ee4615f2c7}
>   could be created for context 0x3
>   fixme:resource:GetGuiResources
>   (0xffffffff,0): stub

What could be the problem?

Edit: I tried removing wine wine directory so that it would auotomatically get recreated when trying to run firefox. Firefox still crashed, but new information was output:

> fixme:system:SetProcessDPIAware stub!
>   fixme:dwmapi:DwmIsCompositionEnabled
>   0x33cfd4
>   fixme:file:MoveFileWithProgressW
>   MOVEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH unimplemented
>   fixme:advapi:SetNamedSecurityInfoW
>   L"C:\windows\system32\gecko\1.0.0\wine_gecko\components\xpti.dat" 1 536870916 (nil) (nil) 0x19d57c (nil)
>   fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange
>   (Handle 0xa71e8d8, overlapped
>   0xa71e8e0): stub
>   fixme:file:MoveFileWithProgressW
>   MOVEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH unimplemented
>   fixme:advapi:SetNamedSecurityInfoW
>   L"C:\windows\system32\gecko\1.0.0\wine_gecko\components\compreg.dat"
>   1 536870916 (nil) (nil) 0x1dbb4ec
>   (nil) wine: configuration in
>   '/home/awakefromnib/.wine' has been
>   updated.
>   fixme:system:SetProcessDPIAware stub!
>   fixme:dwmapi:DwmIsCompositionEnabled
>   0x33fcd4
>   fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange
>   (Handle 0xdfe994, overlapped
>   0xdfe978): stub fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile
>   I/O completion on lock not implemented
>   yet err:ole:CoGetClassObject class
>   {591209c7-767b-42b2-9fba-44ee4615f2c7}
>   not registered
>   err:ole:CoGetClassObject class
>   {591209c7-767b-42b2-9fba-44ee4615f2c7}
>   not registered
>   err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class
>   object
>   {591209c7-767b-42b2-9fba-44ee4615f2c7}
>   could be created for context 0x3
>   fixme:resource:GetGuiResources
>   (0xffffffff,0): stub

Does anything in here make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the underlying problem, but you should try installing to a fresh ~/.wine directory.

```
mv ~/.wine ~/.wine.before_firefox_problem.bak
```

Then re-run Firefox.  As soon as you run wine, it will create a new ~/.wine for itself.  You can remove the old directory later if you don't need anything inside.  It will contain anything related to what you previously did in wine.

Comment: I tried that, and it still crashed. I edited the post to show what it says before it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have hit an unimplemented system call, meaning a Windows API call that's not (yet) implemented by Wine.

If you have installed the latest version of Wine, then your next stop should be in the Wine forums.